# Width of a letter or an alphabet in a font

Tags: wpf, typeface

I want to know what is the width(units) of a particular letter or an alphabet in a particular font.

For example if i type A in Arial 10 pnts how much space its will take in a panel or a text box or a notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I tend not to worry too much about widths, instead leaving it to WPF to format the text nicely in whatever control I'm using.

However, I think you can create a [`FormattedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602325.aspx) object using your typeface and string `"A"` (amongst other things), and then use its [`MinWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.minwidth.aspx) property to get the width in units of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>96th</sub> of an inch.

This code will hopefully get you started:

```
FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(
    "A",
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface("Arial"),
    32,
    Brushes.Black);
double width = ft.MinWidth;
```

On my system, that sets `width` to about `21.343`. If you put an em-dash `—` in where the `A` currently is, you get (as expected) `32.0`, the size you specified for an em in the fifth argument to the `FormattedText` constructor.

Comment: Indeed this was a great help to me...Actually this question was more in context with a situation that i need to solve.Below is the problem statement for the same:

I have a panel in a WPF application, If I increase the size of the text or change the font i want to calculate as to  how much space this text takes to fit in the panel,Further if i want to modify the font style or size by what percentage the space in the panel is occupied by the text..if u can help as to how such a thing can be implemented

Comment: @user3636073, you're better off asking another question with the new details, that way you'll get a much broader group of people looking at it than just me. I'll keep an eye on your questions so I can see it come in.